# cv2.imdecode always returning None

Tags: python, sqlite, opencv, numpy

I am reading binary data [sqlite3.Binary] from a sqlite BLOB in which a JPEG image is stored. The image is written to the DB with

```
img = cv2.imread("images\\image.jpg")
c.execute('INSERT INTO pictures (serial_no, image, height, width) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)',
          (serial_no, sqlite3.Binary(img), img.shape[0], img.shape[1]))
```

Trying to recover the image as follows:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(dbname)
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('SELECT image, height, width FROM pictures WHERE serial_no=?', (serial_no, ))
raw, height, width = c.fetchone()
raw_str = StringIO.StringIO(raw)
arr = np.asarray(bytearray(raw_str.read()), dtype=np.uint8)
img = cv2.imdecode(arr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

The last step always fails and imdecode return None.

What does work, however, is a numpy.reshape:

```
image = arr.copy().reshape((height, width, 3))
```

I've tested with both OpenCV 3.0.0 and OpenCV 2.4.11 where both yield the same, unsatisfying result.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure the blob is actually a jpeg encoded image?  If it is, `arr.reshape(height, width, 3)` should have failed.  It sounds like it might just be an uncompressed image, in which case you'd want `cv.fromarray`, if I recall correctly.

Comment: Good point, Joe, thank you! I've updated the process of how the images wind up in the DB, which is basically storing a ndarray and not, as you correctly point out, a jpeg encoded image.